# testing an Angular2 service method

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm currently using Angular2 RC6. My service is setup as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoModel } from '../models/';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/todos';
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }
  getTodos() {
    return this._http.get(this.baseURL).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

and my test is setup as follows:

```
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';
import { tick, async, inject, TestBed, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

describe('TodoService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Http, useFactory: (backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
          return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
        }, deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        },
        {provide: TodoService, useClass: TodoService},
        {provide: MockBackend, useClass: MockBackend},
        {provide: BaseRequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions}
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should have a method to get all Todos',
    fakeAsync(inject([TodoService, MockBackend], (todoService: TodoService, mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
      let res: Response;
      mockBackend.connections.subscribe(c => {
        expect(c.request.url).toBe('http://localhost:3000/todos');
        let response = new ResponseOptions({body: `[{"id": 5, "item": "do the laundry", "completed": false}]`});
        c.mockRespond(new Response(response));
      });
      todoService.getTodos().subscribe((response) => {
        res = response;
      });
      tick();
      expect(res[0].id).toBe(5);
      expect(res[0].item).toBe('do the laundry');
      expect(res[0].completed).toBe(false);
    }))
  );
});
```

Now when I run the unit test above I get:

```
undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this._http.get(this.baseURL).map(function(res){__cov_70hjYvYxeq9mxqcOWgRVeQ.f['4']++;__cov_70hjYvYxeq9mxqcOWgRVeQ.s['9']++;return res.json();})') (line 9)
```

I'm not sure what exactly I'm missing or if the test needs to be setup differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the missing rxjs map in TodoService

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```